# how to find sum up to kth element of sorted sub-array from l to r?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, sum, dynamic-programming

**Problem:**
We have given an array `A[]` of size `N`. Now we have given `Q` queries, each queries consist of three integer `l,r,k` where:

```
1<=l<=r<=N
1<=k<=(r-l+1)
1<=N,Q<=10^5
```

Now,we want to find out the sum upto the `k` element of the sorted sub-array from `l` to `r`.

**For example:**
Let `N=6` and array element be `5,1,7,4,6,3`
And `Q=1` where `l,r,k` be as `2,5,3`.
then sub-array from `index 2 to index 5` be `{1,7,4,6}`
after sorting it becomes as `{1,4,6,7}`
so sum upto `k=3` term is equal to `(1+4+6)=11`
so answer is `11` .

I have tried using sorting of each sub-array and then sum, it takes `Q*N*log(N)` time complexity in worst case.
Please help to find any better solution within time complexity less than `Q*N` in worst case.

Comment: For time efficient solution, try to do it using dynamic programming

Comment: @SauravSahu how to implement it using dynamic programming?

Comment: It can be solved in nlogn + qlogn by using segment tree (offline) by sorting queries with its r value .
You can learn about segment tree from http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/15890.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396308/subarray-queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to preprocess by using mergesort with the modification that we keep a copy of all the sorted intermediate results.

This preprocessing takes O(nlogn).

Suppose we started with 32 elements.  We would now have:

- 16 sorted 2 element lists
- 8 sorted 4 element lists
- 4 sorted 8 element lists
- 2 sorted 16 element lists
- 1 sorted 32 element list.

We can also precompute the prefix sum of each of these lists in O(nlogn).

Then when faced with a query from l to r, we can identify log(n) of the preprocessed lists that together will cover all elements from l to r.

We can then use binary search to find the value such that there are exactly k smaller elements in the identified lists, and use the prefix sums to calculate the sum.

Comment: Please, elaborate the query part with some pseudo code

Answer (score 0):

If O(Q) >= O(log N):

Sort the original array indices by the sorting order of their elements, for instance:

```
values:  [50, 10, 20, 40, 30] -> [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
indices: [#0, #1, #2, #3, #4] -> [#1, #2, #4, #3, #0]
```

Then, for each query, scan the sorted indices left to right, and add the values of the first `k` elements that you encounter whose indices are within range ([l, r]).  The complexity will be O(QN + N log N) = O(QN) -- again, provided that O(Q) >= O(log N).

There's a way to improve on this by sorting the query ranges first, and then execute all queries in a single scan of the sorted indices, but there's no way to predict how this will affect complexity, short of knowing something special about the lengths of the ranges.